# ¿Que valor le da id a un $_GET?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo el siguiente código donde obtengo datos de la **Urls**

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $url = $_GET['id'];
}
```

Compruebo el valor que me esta dando la variable `$url` como resultado:

> libro-php/

Actualmente se obtiene el dato de tal manera porque tengo el archivo `.htaccess` en **Urls** amigable.

Los datos son correctos a la hora de realizar la consulta:

```
$stmtID = $con->prepare("SELECT idlibro,libro,titulo,precio FROM biblioteca WHERE url=?");
```

Ahora mi pregunta:

**¿Que valor le da el `id` al `$_GET`?**

Si cambio de esta manera el código no funciona todas las variables del archivo pierde su validación por el motivo que ya no recibe el resultado idóneo a la consulta.

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])){
    $url = $_GET['url'];
}
```

¿Qué tiene que ver el `id` en `$_GET`?

> No tengo ningún producto o dato en la base de datos que tenga una columna `id` todos los **IDS** están definidas así `id_producto`, `id_usuario` etc.

**¿Por qué al darle otro nombre no funciona igual?**

> **Actualización**

Archivo .htaccess

```
#Regla Url amigable
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1
```

Comment: puedes agregar parte de la url , o tu configuracion del .htaccess creo que la confusion esta alli, las variables $_GET son aquellas que se envian por la URL , puede que en tu .htaccess tengas definido id en vez de url

Comment: @JackNavaRow Hola, actualice la pregunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como dice el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php):

> `$_GET` es un array asociativo de variables pasado al script actual
>   vía parámetros URL.

Por ejemplo en una URL como esta:

```
http://www.dominio.com/archivo.php?id=1&nombre=Pedro
```

El valor de `$_GET` será un array así:

```
array('id'=>1, 'nombre'=>'Pedro');
```

Si tú quieres obtener los valores de `GET`:

```
$_GET["id"]; //obtienes 1
$_GET["nombre"]; //obtienes Pedro
```

### Para resolver tu problema

Viendo que tu URL se construye así:

```
#Regla Url amigable
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1
```

Bastaría con cambiar en la regla el valor `id` por `url`

```
#Regla Url amigable
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?url=$1
```

Si por el contrario, el valor `url` fuese tomado de otro elemento, o si equivaliese a algún archivo a través del cual construyes URL amigables, entonces tendrías que modificar el nombre del elemento (por ejemplo un elemento HTML)  o el nombre del archivo si fuese un archivo.

---

### Otras cosas sobre `GET`

Supongo que vas a usar `GET` o `POST` más de una vez, por eso me permito dejar algunas indicaciones...

Cuando envías formularios HTML, GET asociará los valores usando como clave el valor de la etiqueta `name` de los elementos.

Ejemplo:

```
<form>
  <input type="number" name="id" />
  <input type="text" name="nombre" />
</form>
```

Si tú quieres igualar las claves que obtendrás vía GET con los nombres de las columnas de tu base de datos, sólo tienes que cambiar el valor de la etiqueta `name` si usas un formulario HTML, o los valores de la URL.

Ejemplo:

**Formulario HTML**

```
<form action="archivo.php" method="GET">
  <input type="number" name="id_producto" placeholder="Introduzca id_producto"/>
  <input type="number" name="id_usuario"  placeholder="Introduzca id_usuario"/>
  <input type="text"   name="url"         placeholder="Introduzca url"/>
</form>
```

Cuando envías este formulario, lo que se produce en realidad es una URL como esta:

```
http://www.dominio.com/archivo.php?id_usuario=1&id_producto=24890&url=example.com/registrar
```

Entonces, con `GET` obtenemos un array con tres claves y sus tres valores respectivos, cada par (clave->valor) es separado por `&` en la URL:

- `id_usuario => 1`
- `id_producto => 24890`
- `url => example.com/registrar`

**archivo.php o archivo que recibe los datos del formulario anterior**

En el archivo PHP recuperarías cada valor así:

```
$_GET["id_producto"];
$_GET["id_usuario"];
$_GET["url"];
```

---

### Notas del Manual de PHP y de la *experiencia*

Algunas indicaciones con respecto al uso de `GET` (las cuales son válidos también para `POST`):

- Cuando los valores vienen de un documento HTML, GET recoge los valores usando la etiqueta `name` de los elementos HTML, no la etiqueta `id`.
- Se suele usar [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php) para verificar que el valor buscado existe en la URL (si existe entre los datos posteados). Por ejemplo, para saber si `id_usuario` fue posteado:

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['id_usuario'])) {
       //existe
  }else{
       //no existe
  }
  ```

  Esta comparación se puede refinar, buscando no sólo si existe, sino si además no está en blanco.
- Esta es una 'superglobal' o una variable automatic global. Significa simplemente que es una variable que está disponible en cualquier parte del script. No hace falta hacer `global $variable;` para acceder a la misma desde funciones o métodos.
- Las variables GET son pasadas vía [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php).
- [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) funciona de la misma manera y en algunas ocasiones es recomendable con respecto a `GET`, pero eso sería otra cuestión.
- **Nunca envíes de manera directa valores recuperados con `GET` o con `POST` ni ningún otro valor proveniente desde el exterior a consultas de la base de datos**. Hacer eso haría el código vulnerable a la Inyección SQL, a través de la cual, usuarios mal intencionados podrían tomar el control no sólo de la base de datos, sino de todo tu sistema. Esos valores deben enviarse mediante consultas preparadas. Aquí en SO hay varias preguntas que tratan este tema.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano :) gracias por responder entonces el identificado del problema es esto: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1` si quiero cambiar a `$_GET['url'];` se debe modificar a: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?url=$1` verdad? o no?

Comment: @May, sí, en teoría... Pero ten en cuenta que si el valor `id` que quieres cambiar por el valor  `url` viene de otro sitio (un formulario HTML, un nombre de archivo que es acortado para crear un URL amigable, etc...) también debes cambiar el valor por `url` en ese sitio. Prueba a cambiar el valor como indicas y haz una prueba. Si falla significa que tendrás que buscar dónde se produce el valor `id` y cambiarlo.

Comment: Sí, exactamente hice los cambios en el `.htaccess` y cambie el `$_GET['url']` y funciona, en el resto del documento no esta definido en otros datos enviados el detalle de producto se envía normalmente desde una etiquete `<a>` así `<a href="'.$url.'">'.$libro.'</a>`

Comment: sólo queda actualizar tu pregunta amigo para que otra persona no cometa el mismo error que yo, dejando toda la documentación que haz dejado solo aclarar este tema para futuros lectores :)

Comment: Ya, ahora la actualizo, no había visto tu edición con la regla `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 7):

**Respuesta corta:**

Cambia tu `.htaccess` a lo siguiente:

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?url=$1
```

**Respuesta Larga:**

Las variables **`$_GET`** en terminos generales son las que se envian por la **URL** explicaria esto pero ya [A.Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/110657/28035) se tomo la molestia
.

Cuando realizas *"URL amigables"* via `.htaccess` o `virtualhost` de igual forma envias parametros via **`GET`** como puedes observar en tu `.htaccess`

```
#Regla Url amigable
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?id=$1
```

estas sobreescibiendo la url e internamente envias el **id**:

```
detalle.php?id=$1
```

Si quieres que cambie esto y recibir `url`en tu codigo deberas cambiar tu `virtualhost` ó `.htaccess` a lo siguiente:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ detalle.php?url=$1
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa es que lo que agregas en `$_GET['nombre']` es el nombre de la variable que se está enviando desde el Front-End hacia el Back-End, en algún archivo tuyo se está haciendo el envío de esa variable con el nombre de `id` y es así como la debes de recibir, si le quieres cambiar el nombre deberías entonces cambiarlo al momento del envío y recibirlo en `php` con el nombre nuevo

Espero haber sido claro en la explicación, de igual forma te dejo este [Link con más información](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.get.php) acerca de las variables GET